# How to disable face detection when using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, face-detection

I realize this is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315260/uiimagepickercontroller-disable-iphone-4s-face-detection-ios-5-1) but that question was never answered and I am seeing the same exact behavior in iOS 6.

I cannot find any setting in UIImagePickerController that will allow me to disable the drawing of green boxes around faces.

Should I be using a different class to access the camera?

Thanks in advance,
LT