# Green box on iPhone 5 camera

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I use an `UIImagePickerController` to show rear camera as background.
Everything works as expected, but in `iPhone 5` and maybe in `iPhone 4s` I have a green box in the image like

[image: face detection]

I think is a face detection feature, but I don't now how to disable it.
Any suggestion?

This is a code snippet that I use for `UIImagePickerController`:
I declare ad UIView in my .h file

```
UIView *overlay;
```

And in the init method of my .m file

```
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM  1.24299

UIImagePickerController *uip;

@try {
      uip = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
      uip.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
      uip.showsCameraControls = NO;
      uip.toolbarHidden = YES;
      uip.navigationBarHidden = YES;
      uip.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
      uip.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(uip.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM, CAMERA_TRANSFORM);
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    [uip release];
    uip = nil;
}
@finally {
    if(uip) {
        [overlay addSubview:[uip view]];
        [overlay release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? Apple added this as a seemingly core feature... users may expect it and be confused if it's not there...

Comment: Because I what display camera view as background application with no other features. Maybe `UIImagePickerController` is not the right controller to use for this, better using `AVCaptureDevice`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746212/cidetector-and-uiimagepickercontroller)

His problem was the other way around, I'm sure if you tweak the settings for the feature detector you'll be able to turn it off, if it's not turnable, just try to run it in a mirrored mode or upside down mode, and it won't be able to detect faces and will seem to be "off"

but i'm pretty sure it can be disabled.

Here's [another reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475387/proper-usage-of-cidetectortracking) that I found
Also make sure to look at the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

### Update:

### Warning: I do not recommend using this at all, it's just to show a way I managed to hide those boxes, it will break sooner or later.

After hacking around a little bit, i managed to track down the subview that holds those little squares and set it's hidden property to YES

simply, at the end of your init code, you makeKeyAndVisible, put in this:

```
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[uip childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] view]
subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
setHidden:YES];
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm doing this in a hurry, but you get the idea, Also while messing around I found that you can control the Camera Iris view and some other features. but this should do your trick 
Also, this won't disable the face detection, meaning when the user finishes selecting, you can find out how many face features where detected !

I also think this will ONLY work on iPhone 4s and up !, you need to test a lot, this is really bad hackery that I don't recommend using on production apps !

Comment: Thanks for response. I saw the link you posted, UIImagePickerController seems don't handle face detection property to set. I will change my implementation with AVCaptureDevice for showing video as background

Comment: Can you Put a code snippet ? I'll try to take a deeper look on my phone cause I'm curious how it works !, thanks :)

Comment: Of course! I edited my post with a code snippet. If you have any other question feel free to tell :)

Comment: Ok managed to hack it, i'll update my answer now on how to do it :)

Comment: -1: This "brute force" method is a terrible idea... this is bound to break in a future update!

Comment: If you slowed down a bit and read my last line You'll notice I said: 
"This is really bad hackery that I don't recommend using on production apps !"